# Python Script for Storage V2 all files properties

Tags: azure-data-lake

[image: Screenprint of adls .]

As part of the audit activities , We are planning to look our all files when was last time got accessed . For that instead of accessing each and every folder individually to get the details if we have python script to give all file details along with file's properties would be great help . Please help us on this

[image: Screenprint for Python Code]

Based above python code , able to retrieve container names. But Not able to find right code for retrieving the file name with files properties.

Comment: Hi, I want to check if the answer works or not. Please let me know:).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [azure-storage-blob 12.3.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) for this case.

The sample code as below:

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

conn_str="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
container_name="datalake1"

container_client=ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str,container_name)

blobs = container_client.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name) // print out the blob name
    print(blob.last_modified) //print out the blob last_modified date

    #use the code below to get all the method/properties can be used for this blob
    print(dir(blob))
```

As mention in the sample code, if you don't know the properties, you can use `print(dir(blob))` to list all the properties or methods can be used for the blob.

The test result:

[image]